# JQuery: pass $(this).parent(); to method?

Tags: jquery, parent

I have a simple script:

```
$('.expand').each(function(i){ 
var _Expand = $(this).parent();
    ExpGroupBy(_Expand);
});
```

Trying to pass the `<tr>` of all `<td>` with the class 'expand'

However firebug keeps popping up the Error:

> 'TypeError:
>   formObj.getElementsByTagName is not a
>   function'

Any ideas?

Thanks ^^

Comment: ExpGroupBy is a normal function used in a Sharepoint DataView, it normally takes a simple:

ExpGroupBy(this);

Comment: the bug seems to be elsewhere in your code.  what's in ExpGroupBy?

Comment: OK, see my answer then.  I think I guessed correctly :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as the function understands that the parameter is the jQuery object and not the DOM element itself.  If the function expects a DOM element reference, you can easily do that like this...

```
$('.expand').each(function(i){
  var _Expand = $(this).parent();
  ExpGroupBy(_Expand[0]);  // Note the [0]
});
```

Answer (score 3):

`parent()` returns a jQuery object. Try this instead:

```
$(".expand").parent().each(function() { 
    ExpGroupBy(this);
});
```

Comment: Nice, in firefox this is faster then Josh Stodala's answer and will give the same result

Answer (score 0):

If ExpGroupBy expects DOM element call it as `ExpGroupBy(_Expand[0])`

Answer (score 0):

get(0) returns the element encapsulated in jquery object. You can use _Expand.get(0) as well